# Showing that if a function is bounded and has increasing Laurent coefficient then all positive powers coefficient must tend to 0

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Let $a_n^k$ be real coefficients, such that for each $n\geq 0$ $(a_n^k)_{k\geq0}$ is monotonely increasing and such that 
$$ 
 \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n^k \lambda^n
$$
is a holomorphic function on $k+\epsilon <|\lambda| < k+1-\epsilon$. Finally assume that the so defined function on $\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}, ||\lambda|-n|>\epsilon, \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is bounded.

I would like to show that $a_n^k\to 0$ for all $n>0$. Intuitively I'm convinced however, if I take a sequence $N<\lambda_N<N+1$ and I want to use the boundedness, I can't be sure that there is no cancelation from the negative coefficients getting bigger.

Is there an elegant prove? (If at all, a counter example would blow me away but would be even more important to know)

Comment: Do you know an integral formula for the Laurent coefficients?

Comment: I ask whether you know the formula. With the intention to make you think about how it helps you here.

Comment: Good. Will you write an answer? Or would you prefer if I write one?

Comment: Actually I figured that in my case the resulting function is only bounded on a strip $|\Im \lambda|<c$ in which case $sin( \lambda)$ is a counterexample :(.

Answer (score 0):

The integral formula for Laurent coefficients gives that for any path $\gamma_k$ around zero such that $k+\epsilon<|\gamma_k | <k+1-\epsilon$ one has
$$
   a_n^k = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_k} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \mathrm{d}z.
$$
By the boundedness of $f$ on then sees that $a_n^k\to 0$ for all $n\geq1$ as $k\mapsto\infty$ while $a_0^k$ must be bounded and hence cenverges.

Comment: due to Daniel Fischer