# Conditions on Laurent series coefficient of function bounded on every strip $|\Im\lambda|<c$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Let $a_n^k$ be real coefficients, such that for each $n\geq 0$ $(a_n^k)_{k\geq0}$ is monotonely increasing and such that 
$$ 
 \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n^k \lambda^n
$$
is a holomorphic function on $k+\epsilon <|\lambda| < k+1-\epsilon$. Assume that the so defined function on $\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}, ||\lambda|-n|>\epsilon, \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is bounded on every strip $|\Im\lambda|<c$ intersected with its domain. Finally assume that $k+1-\epsilon$ is the convergence radius of the $k$-th series.

I would like to show that $a_n^k\to 0$ for all $n>0$. Intuitively I'm convinced however, without the constraint on the convergence radius this wouldn't be true since $\sin(\lambda)$ would be a counter example.

Here my very sketchy idea how this could go (which doesn't quite work). I started using that the convergence radius can be computed using Cauchy-Hadamard to be
$$
  \limsup_{n\mapsto\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n^k|} = \frac{1}{k+1-\epsilon}
$$
which is monotonely decreasing in $k$. Hence $\sqrt[n]{|a_n^k|}$ is essentially decreasing in $k$ which means that $a_n^k$ are essentially negative. If I can show that allmost all coefficients are negative somehow then I obtain that each $a_n^k\lambda^n$ is bounded except if I get cancellation from negative powers. Maybe I can bound the cancellation using a similar argument on the negative part and the lower bounds. For this I could use (what I didn't mention) that $f(\lambda^{-1})$ fullfils the same conditions. Hence essentially all coefficients are negative. I just need to understand what the essentially means in all this and how to use it. Any idea is very wellcome.

This question is a second version of my former question [same question but with uniform boundedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965640/showing-that-if-a-function-is-bounded-and-has-increasing-laurent-coefficient-the).

Comment: I figured that at any time the series  obtained using only the positive coefficients has convergence radius infinity, hence the one with only negative coefficients fulfills the radius condition. This might help construct a counter example.